# Continuous one-to-one mapping of a compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Prove that every continuous one-to-one mapping of a compact space is topological.

Does this problem statement refer to a mapping of a compact space **to itself**?

If so, suppose the mapping is $f:A\rightarrow A$, where $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous and 1-1. We must show that $f$ is also onto (and hence bijective), and the inverse image $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

For any compact subset $B\subseteq A$, the set $f(B)$ is compact. Since closed subsets of a compact set are compact, for any closed subset $B\subseteq A$ , the set $f(B)$ is compact (and so, closed and bounded). How might that help?

Comment: What does it mean that a mapping is *topological*? Did you mean to say *embedding*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that if $f:A\to B$ is continuous and one-to-one, and if $A$ is compact, then $f$ maps $A$ homeomorphically to $f[A]$. As written, though, it is incorrect. We need to know that $B$ has the property that compact subsets are closed. That's what will allow the proof to work.

It should be clear that such an $f$ maps $A$ bijectively and continuously to $f[A]$ (considered as a subspace of $B$). It remains to show, then, that $f$ maps closed subsets of $A$ to (relatively) closed subsets of $f[A],$ since this is equivalent (why?) to showing that $g:f[A]\to A$ given by $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is a continuous function.

As a side note, "bounded" doesn't necessarily make sense for general spaces. It does suggest that you may be working with metric spaces, however, rather than arbitrary topological spaces. *If that is the case*, then there's no need to make the additional assumption that compact subsets of $B$ are closed, because this is always true in metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be defined as $f(X) = X/2$. Then $f$ is continuous and one-one but not onto.

Answer (score -1):

This question comes from an exercise (Ex 3, pg 66) of Ahlfor "complex Analysis, 2nd edition".

In Rudin "Principle of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd ed" there is a theorem (Theorem 4.17, page 90) state that:

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous $1$-$1$ mapping of a compact metric space $X$ **onto** a metric space $Y$. Then the inverse mapping $f$ inverse is a continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$.

According to this theorem we need onto in the statement of the exercise or just show for the function $f\colon A \to f[A]$.

Answer (score -1):

So there is a general result from Hall and Spencer's Elementary Topology, pg. 76, to the effect that a 1-1 continuous map from a general compact space onto a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. For example. a Cantor perfect set is not homeomorphic with a  bounded closed interval of the real line. That's because a continuous map of a connected set is comnected. A fortiori there is no 1-1 continuous map of a Cantor set onto a closed interval.

Submitted by Edgar Cohen, Ph. D.